# Context Menu Items and command line programs

Tags: windows, script, windows-registry

I am currently trying to create a context menu item so that you can click on an executable file and select a scan option from the context menu, a command line program will then be launched with the working directory defined as C:\Program Files\Scanner and the input file (file I  right-click on) will be the insert in the %1% parameter.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\Shell\Scan\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k cd  "C:\\Program Files\\Scanner" & "C:\\Program Files\\Scanner\\scanner.exe" "%1%""
```

I am having a nightmare trying to get this work, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's **`%1`**, not `%1%`
2. You must also escape the inner quotation marks:

   ```
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\Shell\Scan\command]
   @="cmd.exe /k cd /d \"C:\\Program Files\\Scanner\" && scanner.exe \"%1\""
   ```
3. The `/d` option must be given to `cd`, to also change the current drive letter in *cmd* (if your file is on another drive).
4. Specifying full path to `scanner.exe` is not necessary, because after you `cd` it will be in the current directory.

Comment: @James: One thing I forgot. You must use `cd /d`, not `cd`, otherwise the command will fail when the file is on another drive.